# xPages Extension Library Application Layout - Bootstrap options not showing

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I've installed the latest Extension Library on my designer machine and my server.  If I do "tell osgi..." at the server, I get, among other things...

```
[1130:0002-0BDC] 10/26/2016 05:16:58 PM  13 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_17_20160428-0214
[1130:0002-0BDC] 10/26/2016 05:16:58 PM  36 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.theme.bootstrap4_9.0.1.v00_16_20160119-2239
```

I've enabled com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library and com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.library in my application.  I don't see the org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.library as a choice, but I think that's to be expected.  I have read that bootstrap is now baked in to the ExtLib.

There are no Bootstrap themes available in the theme dropdown.  I entered "Bootstrap3.2.0" manually, and my application does load the Bootstrap framework.

The big problem is that when I drag the Application Layout control onto a custom control, I don't get the "Bootstrap Application Layout" option.  I just get "Basic... and "OneUI..."  What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to install the Bootstrap4Xpages plugin as well?  Other posts on this topic come close, but I haven't found anyone with this exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you install into your client?  The Ext. Library is two update sites.  One specific for the server and the other specific for Designer.  I suspect you installed the server version into Designer and that's causing your problem.  Look closely at the downloaded zip from OpenNTF.  You should be able to find 2 zipped update sites inside.  I think there are actually 2 more with source if I remember.  You don't need those I believe.

Comment: I think you nailed it, David.  I missed the reference to the Designer update site in the Readme file.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a champ.  Bootstrap configuration is now available.  Thanks again.  I would have had trouble finding that.